# SVN checkout reporting unknown host

Tags: svn, hostname, checkout

I have just done a fresh install of redmine and svn, I am getting this error when trying to check out:

`svn: Unknown hostname redmine.mydomain.com`

It definitely exists, I can ping it, view it etc. I've searched for a couple of hours with no luck. I am on Ubuntu 12.04, and I am not using a proxy.

Edit: `svn info`, `svn log` etc report:

`svn: '.' is not a working copy`

Comment: We need more info to help you.  Can you ping redmine.mydomain.com.  Can you ping REDMINE.MYDOMAIN.COM from the same host you are checking out from ?

Comment: I can ping redmine.mydomain.com from my own PC but from the machine redmine is hosted on it says unknown host, pinging mydomain.com from the machine redmine is hosted on works though.

Comment: I was missing an A record on the subdomain. I've added it now, so hopefully that will fix it. Will check in a couple of hours.

Comment: Well I waited long enough, even restarted everything and I am still getting unknown host. I can ping redmine.mydomain.com on my own pc fine but not on the machine redmine and svn is hosted on.

Comment: Can you ping other domains from that box (ie is DNS resolving)?

Comment: I didn't even think of that, no I can't! :o No idea what this means though.

Comment: I was messing with this before and moved resolv.conf somewhere else, I've now put it back and I can resolve all domains now including the subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I moved resolv.conf from /etc and never put it back, I put it back now and can resolve all domains and subdomains etc.